# Why does my switch statement always goes to default case?

Tags: c, switch-statement

The default case is always executed in this switch statement, no matter what I type at the prompts.
When I type in, for example, 'A' for the second question, it prints out `Invalid code entered`.

```
do{
    printf("Please enter the quantity of dishes.\n");
    scanf(" %d", &quantity);

    printf("Please enter the dishes code.\n");
    scanf("%d", &dishes);

    switch (dishes){
    case'A':case'a':sushiA(quantity);
        break;
    case'B':case'b':sushiB(quantity);
        break;
    case'C':case'c':sushiC(quantity);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid code entered.\n");
        break;
    }

    printf("Do you still want to enter next dishes?[Y=Yes, N=No]\n");
    scanf(" %c", &answer);
} while (toupper(answer) == 'Y');
```

Why is that?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then use a debugger (`gdb`) to run your code step by step and inspect values of variables.

Comment: As others have said, you're reading an integer (%d) into a char (%c). If you type 65 as the dishes code, does it go to the sushiA case?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for the info! Will look into it!

Comment: @PkP Yeah, type in 65 really goes into sushiA case.... wow, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Also read the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) ; you really *should* test its return count of scanned items

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Return count of scanned items? Sorry I don't really understand that ...

Comment: Did'nt I told you to *read the documentation* ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch oh that one can click... okay i know now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're scanning into dishes as an integer `(%d)`, but then treating it as a character (`case 'A'`).  Try doing your scanf for dishes as a `%c` instead

Answer (score 1):

If `dishes` is a `char`, doing `scanf("%d", &dishes);` is wrong.
It scans a wrong value into the variable - a number, not a character code. It probably won't scan anything (zero?) when you type "A" because it expects a number.
Also, it's (probably) writing over unallocated memory due to different type allocating sizes (`sizeof(char) != sizeof(int)`).

Use `scanf("%c", &dishes)`.

---

Side note: learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Oh now I know... Thanks! Will search how to use a debugger, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
do{
printf("Please enter the quantity of dishes.\n");
scanf(" %d", &quantity);

printf("Please enter the dishes code.\n");
scanf("%c", &dishes);  //This line had an error

switch (dishes){
case'A':case'a':sushiA(quantity);
    break;
case'B':case'b':sushiB(quantity);
    break;
case'C':case'c':sushiC(quantity);
    break;
default:
    printf("Invalid code entered.\n");
    break;
}

printf("Do you still want to enter next dishes?[Y=Yes, N=No]\n");
scanf(" %c", &answer);
} while (toupper(answer) == 'Y');
```

Your scanf takes dishes as integer but your switch case treats it as character .

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate that!

Comment: while compiling use -Wall flag and check for gdb (it is a debugger) .. These two things will help you a lot :)

Comment: Does this two available in Visual Studio 2013? Because I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. Thanks!

Comment: Actually these are for gcc compiler , I dont think so they are availaible for Visual studio but I am sure visual studio must have some debuggers